# Add settings fields on options discussion admin page

Tags: settings-api

### Problem description

I'm searching for a way to add a settings section/settings fields to the `~/wp-admin/options-discussion.php` page exactly [where Core calls](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.1/wp-admin/options-discussion.php#L246)…

```
do_settings_sections('discussion');
```

### How to

When I register the setting and add the settings field, nothing appears:

```
function register_setting()
{
    register_setting(
         'discussion'
        ,$this->option_name
        ,array( $this, 'sanitize_setting' )
    );
}

public function add_settings_field()
{
    add_settings_field(
         $this->option_name
        ,__( 'Label', 'wpse_textdomain' )
        ,array( $this, 'render_field' )
        ,'discussion'
        ,'discussion'
        ,array()
    );
}
```

### Debug/inspect

Now I was curious why nothing appeared and dumped the global that holds the settings section right below that line in core:

```
var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_settings_sections'] );
```

The output was a plain simple `NULL`.

### Question

> How does one register a settting there, **without** registering the section with `add_settings_section( 'discussion', __( 'Title', 'textdomain' ), 'callback', 'discussion' );` first?

### Reason

The reason why I ask for *"without registering the setting without the section"* is plain simple: If another plugin registers the same section afterwards, it would overwrite/override the added section.

**EDIT** To make it more clear what I'm asking for. I'm aware that there're two sections `default` & `avatars` already present on the page and that I can hook in there. Point is that I don't want to hook into existing core feature settings, but *below* them, right into the settings sections that core *should* output with `do_settings_sections( 'discussion' );`. Point also is, that the `discussion` page was never registered by core and therefore can't get used as `do_settings_section()` aborts without being able to loop through any (not) registered pages. I'm fully ok with an answer that confirms that and states: *No, doesn't work. Is a bug.* or **even better** creates or helps creating *a patch*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call `add_settings_section()` first, pass a unique ID and assign it to the *page* (poor name) `discussion`:

```
add_settings_section( 'ads_id', 'Extra Settings', 'ads_description', 'discussion' );
```

Then register a callback to save your field(s) …

```
// Register a callback
register_setting(
    'discussion',
    'ads',
    'trim'
);
```

… and then register one or more fields:

```
// Register the field for the "avatars" section.
add_settings_field(
    'ads',
    'Test field',
    'ads_show_settings',
    'discussion',
    'ads_id',
    array ( 'label_for' => 'ads_id' )
);
```

Here is a very simple example:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'ads_register_setting' );

/**
 * Tell WP we use a setting - and where.
 */
function ads_register_setting()
{
    add_settings_section(
        'ads_id',
        'Extra Settings',
        'ads_description',
        'discussion'
    );

    // Register a callback
    register_setting(
        'discussion',
        'ads',
        'trim'
    );
    // Register the field for the "avatars" section.
    add_settings_field(
        'ads',
        'Test field',
        'ads_show_settings',
        'discussion',
        'ads_id',
        array ( 'label_for' => 'ads_id' )
    );
}

/**
 * Print the text before our field.
 */
function ads_description()
{
    ?><p class="description">This is the description</p><?php
}

/**
 * Show our field.
 *
 * @param array $args
 */
function ads_show_settings( $args )
{
    $data = esc_attr( get_option( 'ads', '' ) );

    printf(
        '<input type="text" name="ads" value="%1$s" id="%2$s" />',
        $data,
        $args['label_for']
    );
}
```

Note the fifth parameter for `add_settings_field()`.

#### Result

[image]

Comment: For later readers: I have to note that the _main problem_ I had with the sanitize callback not working was, that I hooked into `load-options-discussion.php`. This is (kind of) wrong as the callback won't work unless you hook the registration of the setting (`register_setting()`) to `admin_init`. Point is that it's kind of hard to abort the class on other admin pages this way to not use memory when it's not needed (check `'update' === $_POST['action']` for example), but it works.